# Using mechanize with regular expression to select specific text in links to follow

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri, mechanize

I have a page as follows:

```
#<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO11_IIIE"
   "/me/secure/ViewSample.do?id=211112">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO15_IIIE"
   "/me/secure/do?id=211113">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO16_IIC"
   "/me/secure/ViewSample.do?id=211114">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO17_IIC"
   "/me/secure/ViewSample.do?id=211116">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO17_IIIE"
   "/me/secure/ViewSample.do?id=211115">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO19_IID"
   "/me/secure/ViewSample.do?id=211117">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO21_IIC"
   "/me/secure/ViewSample.do?id=211118">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO21_IIIE"
   "/me/secure/do?id=211119">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "TCO23_IIC"
   "/me/secure/do?id=211120">
```

I am writing a script to try to follow the links which have 'ViewSample' in them (and then download specific links ending in fq but not relevant for this question).

I am a bit confused as to how to do this as I think the method `.search` and `.links_with` require exact strings for the whole link text (?or is it the href???). So I think I need a regular expression in the first line in the code below:

```
master_page.search("ViewSample") do |download_list_link|
    download_list_page = agent.get(download_list_link[:href])

    download_list_page.search("td > a") do |link|
        if link.content.include?("fq.gz")
            out_file = File.new("downloaded_file", "w")
            out_file.puts($agent.get_file(link[:href]))
            out_file.close
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: That's not a page, that's Mechanize's representation of the page as an object. Please supply the HTML you're parsing. Read "[mcve]".

Comment: The html is in the format <a href="/lablink/secure/ViewSample.do?id=229651">TCO23_IIIE</a></td> for each link

Comment: From "[mcve]": "If a web page problem requires HTML, some JavaScript and a stylesheet, include all three." Provide us usable HTML; Don't make us rebuild a HTML page just to help you. You're asking us to use our time to help you, and making it harder for us to do so, which takes away time from helping others.

Comment: Im just looking for how a regex can be used to get the text I need. From that point of view I have provided the minimal example. I think the question is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `select` is for:

```
page.links.select{|link| link.href[/ViewSample/]}
```

or

```
page.search('a').select{|a| a[:href][/ViewSample/]}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I also managed to get it to work with master_page.links_with(:href => /ViewSample/)